# How to merge with a local trunk?

Tags: svn, merge

Okay..this sounds very easy, but I could not find it by googling or searching stackoverflow.

I have a trunk and created a branch of it.

I made a few changes on the trunk and committed the changes. I know that I can do

**svn merge url-of-the-trunk** to merge, but can I do it locally? I've tried **svn merge ../../trunk**, but looks like it doesn't work.

Why do I need to download changes from the server when I have all the changes locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN doesn't store history on disk. Since merge analyzes history it has to have access to the server.

Working copy on disk stores only base version for every item to be able to detect modifications.

Thus the working copy of the trunk on your disk has not enough information for merge.